# Progres Bar SetProgres

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, count, progress-bar

I have two numbers. Current score and maxScore. For example 0/1000.
I have several levels. Each level has its own experience. 1000, 2000, 3000. When the User scores from 0 to 1000, the progress bar fills from start to End. But when the user has scored 1000 points, he should now score 2000 points. Then the progress bar is filled from the middle, and not from the beginning, as is the case from 0 to 1000.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var progressBar:UIProgressView!

func SetProgress() {
let currentScore = getScore() //return Int
let maxScore     = getMaxScore() // return Int


            progressBar.progress = Float(currentScore / maxScore)
         
}
```

Comment: Try to explain a bit better. You appear to be asking how to set the `.progress` property of a progress bar... but that is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @DonMag Im editing my question

Comment: When you're changing from "max score of 1000 to max score of 2000" are you setting the user's current score back to Zero?

Comment: @DonMag No. I need the user to keep earning points from 1000 to 2000. But the progress bar has to start over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - you need to track another piece of information... let's call it the "base score".

The user starts at Zero, with a goal of 1000. As he earns points, you're setting the progress as a percentage of 1000:

```
// supposing the curentScore is 900, maxScore is 1000
progress.progress = Float(currentScore)/Float(maxScore)
```

the bar is 90% filled.

When the user reaches 1000, you set a new goal of 2000, and you want to track the progress ***not*** as a percentage of `currentScore` to `maxScore`. Instead, you want to track the progress from ***previous*** `maxScore` to ***new*** `maxScore`.

So, something like this:

```
func setProgress() -> Void {
    let currentScore = getScore()
    let maxScore     = getMaxScore()
    
    // for example, if user is at:
    //  Level 1 == 0
    //  Level 2 == 1000
    //  Level 3 == 2000
    let levelBase = getLevelBaseScore()

    let curVal = Float(currentScore - levelBase)
    let maxVal = Float(maxScore - levelBase)
    
    progressBar.progress = curVal / maxVal
}
```

So, `getLevelBaseScore()` should return the previous level's max score.

Examples:

If user is at "Level 1" and his current score is 750:

```
    let currentScore = getScore()           // returns 750
    let maxScore     = getMaxScore()        // returns 1000
    
    let levelBase = getLevelBaseScore()     // returns Zero for Level 1
    
    let curVal = Float(750 - 0)             // == 750
    let maxVal = Float(1000 - 0)            // == 1000
    
    // 750 / 1000 == 0.75 or 75% of the bar
    progressBar.progress = curVal / maxVal
```

If user is at "Level 2" and his current score is 1100:

```
    let currentScore = getScore()           // returns 1100
    let maxScore     = getMaxScore()        // returns 2000
    
    let levelBase = getLevelBaseScore()     // returns 1000 for Level 2
    
    let curVal = Float(1100 - 1000)         // == 100
    let maxVal = Float(2000 - 1000)         // == 1000
    
    // 100 / 1000 == 0.10 or 10% of the bar
    progressBar.progress = curVal / maxVal
```

If user is at "Level 2" and his current score is 1600:

```
    let currentScore = getScore()           // returns 1600
    let maxScore     = getMaxScore()        // returns 2000
    
    let levelBase = getLevelBaseScore()     // returns 1000 for Level 2

    let curVal = Float(1600 - 1000)         // == 600
    let maxVal = Float(2000 - 1000)         // == 1000
    
    // 600 / 1000 == 0.60 or 60% of the bar
    progressBar.progress = curVal / maxVal
```

If user is at "Level 3" and his current score is 2250:

```
    let currentScore = getScore()           // returns 2250
    let maxScore     = getMaxScore()        // returns 3000
    
    let levelBase = getLevelBaseScore()     // returns 2000 for Level 3
    
    let curVal = Float(2250 - 2000)         // == 250
    let maxVal = Float(3000 - 2000)         // == 1000
    
    // 250 / 1000 == 0.25 or 25% of the bar
    progressBar.progress = curVal / maxVal
```

Comment: Thanks! Its  best answer  !

Answer (score 1):

```
let currentScore = 25 
let maxScore     = 50 

@IBOutlet weak var progress: UIProgressView!

progress.progress = Float(currentScore)/Float(maxScore)
```

i hope it will work